# Unexpected behaviour of "For Each wks In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets", it affects more column that it should be

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

i did this code that works pretty well exept the last part:

The behaviour of last part should be that ".Interior.Color" and ".Value" affected until the last populated column, instead it affects the first cell of many other columns. Any ideas?

```
  Sub Sample_Workbook()
        
        'Creation of new workbook
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False        
        Workbooks.Add
        
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "etc.xlsx"
        
        'following variable is declared for sending mail purpose
        SourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        
        Set this = Workbooks("Sample")
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        wb.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
        Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)
        wb.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(2)
        Set ws3 = wb.Sheets(3)
        ws1.Name = "Sheet1"
        ws2.Name = "Sheet2"
        ws3.Name = "Sheet3"
        
        
        'Model the new excel with the requirements:
        Dim Population, Population2 As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long
        Dim sampleSize As Long
        Dim unique As Boolean
        Dim i As Long, d As Long, n As Long
        
        
        'following function perfoms all the calculations and copy and pasting        
            
            doTheJob x, y, z, num, q           
            doTheJob x, y, z, num, q 
            doTheJob x, y, z, num, q 
                
        'copy and paste the remaining sheets from the sample files
            Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "Sample2.xlsx"
                Sheets("Sheetx").Copy After:= _
                 Workbooks(SourceWorkbook).Sheets(6)
            Workbooks("Sample2.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ws1.Select
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End Sub

'these will make the variable available to all modules of this macro Workbook
Public SourceWorkbook As String
Public this, wb As Workbook
Public data As Range
Public output As Range
Public ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Public LastCol As Long
Public wks As Worksheet
Public iCol As Long




'FUNCTION
Sub doTheJob(x As String, y As String, z As String, num As Integer, q As String)

    'beginning logic.
    this.Worksheets(x).Activate

Set Population = Range("a3", Range("a3").End(xlDown))
    sampleSize = this.Worksheets("SNOW Reports").Range(y).Value

Set r = Population
    lastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    firstRow = r.Row


    For i = 1 To sampleSize
   Do
   
    unique = True
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(firstRow, lastRow)
    
        For d = 1 To i - 1
        'wb.Sheets(z).Activate
        
          If wb.Sheets(z).Cells(d + 1, 50) = n Then
            unique = False
            Exit For
            End If
        Next d
        
          If unique = True Then
          Exit Do
          End If
        
    Loop
    
    Set data = this.Worksheets(x).Range("a" & n, Range("a" & n).End(xlToRight))
    Set output = wb.Worksheets(z).Range("A" & i + 1)
     
    output.Resize(data.Rows.Count, data.Columns.Count).Value = data.Value
        'THE NEXT LINE IS JUST FOR DELETEING LAST COLUMN PURPOSE
    wb.Worksheets(z).Cells(1, 50) = "REF COL"
    wb.Worksheets(z).Cells(i + 1, 50) = n
    
 this.Worksheets(x).Activate
    
Next i

    'delete REF COL:
       With wb.Sheets(z)
            .Columns(50).Delete
        End With
    
    'copy and paste header:
    Set data = this.Worksheets(x).Range("a2", Range("a2").End(xlToRight))
    Set output = wb.Sheets(z).Range("A1")
    
    output.Resize(data.Rows.Count, data.Columns.Count).Value = data.Value
     
'_________________________________________________________________________________________________________

'copy and paste into new sheet with recorded macro
    
   wb.Activate
   Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(num)).Name = q
   wb.Worksheets(z).Cells.Copy Destination:=wb.Worksheets(q).Range("A1")
             
    'create columns and add color and text dinamically
    For Each wks In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        With wks
            For iCol = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column To 2 Step -1
                .Columns(iCol).Insert
                With Cells(1, iCol)
                .Interior.Color = 65535
                .Value = Cells(1, iCol - 1) & " - Comparison"
                End With
            Next iCol
        End With
    Next wks

End Sub
```

Comment: `With Cells(1, iCol)` <--- this is implicitly referring to the active sheet. As is the `Cells(1, iCol - 1)` in `.Value = Cells(1, iCol - 1) & " - Comparison"`

Comment: @BigBen how should it be? Because active sheet is the correct one in that moment

Comment: `With .Cells(1, iCol)` to refer to `wks` (add the period `.`), and add `wks.` before `Cells(1, iCol - 1)`.

Comment: @BigBen did this: With .Cells(1, iCol)
                .Interior.Color = 65535
                .Value = wks.Cells(1, iCol - 1) & " - Comparison" but had the same result

Comment: I'd use `For iCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 2 Step -1`, assuming that row 1 is populated.

Comment: Is this instance `xlCellTypeLastCell` works just fine (and, IMO, is less fuss). The above would have merit if you weren't creating fresh sheets and filing the data on the fly (as you are), but instead you were 1) re-using existing sheets without first clearing out the used range and 2) Row 1 is always fully populated (i.e. has cell contents in every cell of the copies data).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're aiming to do, the following does what you want.

- The code could be approached differently (and possibly made more efficient), if the larger context was known
- However, I sense  this is just a stage in your development, so have stayed with your approach (wherever reasonable).

```
' I suggest this goes to the top of the sub (no need for public declaration)
' Note the shorthand declaration: 'lgRow&' is the same as `lgRow as Long'
    Dim lgRow&, lgCol&, lgLastRow&
             

' Replaces the code starting with the next comment 
    'create columns and add color and text dynamically
    For Each wks In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        With wks
            For lgCol = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column To 2 Step -1
                
                ' Insert a column (not sure why you're not doing this after the last column also)
                .Columns(lgCol).Insert
                
                ' Get last row with data in the column 1 to the left
                With .Columns(lgCol - 1)
                    lgLastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                End With
                    
                ' In the inserted column:
                ' o Set cell color
                ' o Set value to corresponding cell to the left, appending ' - Comparison'
                For lgRow = 1 To lgLastRow
                    With .Cells(lgRow, lgCol)
                        .Interior.Color = 65535
                        .Value = .Offset(0, -1) & " - Comparison"
                    End With
                Next lgRow
            Next lgCol
        End With
    Next wks
```

Note 1: Not sure of the reason, but your code inserts the 'comparison columns' after each column, except the last column (of the copied data). If I understand your intent correctly, I'd assume you want to do this for the last column also. If that's true:

```
'change this line
    For lgCol = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column To 2 Step -1
'To:
    For lgCol = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column + 1 To 2 Step -1
```

Note 2: My code changes write `<cell value> & " - Comparison"` to all cells in each column, down to the last non-blank cell in each 'compared' column (including blank cells above that). If you want to do that write for all rows in the copied data range (whether cells are blank or not) you could simplify the code by placing the following:

```
' Insert this:
    lgLastRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
'above line:
    For lgCol = ....
```

And remove this:

```
    ' Get last row with data in the column 1 to the left
    With .Columns(iCol - 1)
        lgLastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
```

Other Note / Pointers:

1. Recommend `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules (just saves a lot of debugging due to typos)
2. There's no need (and it's not good practice) to declare `Public` variables that are only used locally in a given `Sub` or `Function`. Instead, declare same locally (usually at the top of the `Sub` or `Function`).
3. It's good practice to use the leading characters of variable names to ID the data type. Can be any length, but is commonly 1, 2 or 3 chars (coder's preference). e.g. Above I used `lg` to ID long data types. Similarly, I use `in` for `Integer`, `st` for `String`, `rg` for `Range`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how widely used Hungarian notation is currently, and there was always a debate on whether or not it was a good thing.  I mean, it can be useful, just IMO at the expense of readability (and some brevity which is secondary).

Comment: Re 3) What you're advocating here is "systems hungarian" which is widely discredited.   On the other hand, "Apps hungarian" can be useful.  [A good read](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) (not about vba, but still relevant)

Comment: @Chris Strickland: Agreed there's for and against. In languages where data type is implicit (versus explicit), I opt for purpose naming. In languages (like vba) where it's explicit, I stick with the 'tried and proven' as I find it makes debugging easier.